# Can I use two Haproxy ingress controller in two different namespaces in the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

If I have deployments for two haproxy ingress controllers in two different namespaces on the same cluster, but the functionality of haproxy ingress controller is misbehaving. I just wanted to know if I can create two haproxy deployments in two namespaces and use them effortlessly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
In order to achieve this you should use correctly configured RBAC and `--namespace-whitelist` flag to point to correct namespace.

[HAProxy documentation](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-9r1/traffic-management/kubernetes-ingress-controller/#customizing-the-haproxy-ingress-controller) says you can whitelist/blacklist namespaces HAProxy uses:

```
--namespace-whitelist
```

> The controller watches all namespaces, but you can specify a specific
>   namespace to watch. You can specify this setting multiple times.

```
--namespace-blacklist
```

> The controller watches all namespaces, but you can blacklist a
>   namespace that you do not want to watch for changes. You can specify
>   this setting multiple times.

You can customize the ingress controller Deployment resource in the file [haproxy-ingress.yaml](https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/deploy/haproxy-ingress.yaml) in the repository https://github.com/haproxytech/ by adding any of the following arguments under the section spec.template.spec.containers.args

You deployments should look like

```
spec:
      serviceAccountName: haproxy-ingress-service-account
      containers:
      - name: haproxy-ingress
        image: haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress
        args:
          - --default-ssl-certificate=default/tls-secret
          - --configmap=default/haproxy-configmap
          - --default-backend-service=haproxy-controller/ingress-default-backend
          - --namespace-whitelist=mynamespace1
```

Comment: Yes, I figures out the same. We will have to add annotation also in the ingress file as kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "ingress-$(POD_NAMESPACE)"